# How to access a modified state from a different file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to access an array that is modified from Screen1. How can I get access to this array from Screen2? Is there a way to do this?

**Screen1.tsx**

```
function Screen1() {

    const getData = () => {
    
       data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
       data.filter((i) => i < 3)
       return data;
    }

    return (

    <View> 
      <Text>Returning JSX</Text>
    </View>

    )
}
```

**Screen2.tsx**

```
const Screen2 = ({ navigation }) => {
   
    const arr = [1, 2] // modified arr from screen 1
    
    return (
        
       {arr.map((i) => (
          <Button
            onPress={() =>
              navigation.navigate("Screen1")
            }
          />
        ))}
    )

}
```

Comment: You can use a [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Could you give me an example with the code?

Comment: There is an example in the documentation I linked.

Comment: What is a non-JSX component? What is a JSX component for that matter? Can you provide a more complete/comprehensive example for what you're trying to do?

Comment: @DrewReese By JSX component, I meant that Screen1 is returning only JSX. I was wondering how I could pass `data` from Screen1 to Screen2 without returning it from Screen1.

Comment: ***All*** React components ***must*** return valid JSX; they return nothing else but JSX. How do these two screen components relate to one another?

Comment: See the updated code.

Comment: @DrewReese Do you have a solution or do you need more clarification?

Comment: I could propose a solution, it likely wouldn't be much different than @HunterMcMillen's suggestion. How dow these two components relate to each other. Is one rendering the other? What is the array you want to share? What have you tried on your own already to share an array from screen 1 component?

Comment: The screens are part of a stack navigator. Screen 1 lays on top of Screen 2 and `onPress` takes it to Screen 1. The `data` array is initialized and modified in Screen 1 and I want to share it to Screen 2. If @HunterMcMillen's suggestion is the best way to handle this, could you post an example using the code? I am pretty new to React Context and don't understand it a lot. If there is a way to share the const `getData`, I could use that too.

Comment: I meant in code, how do they relate. What is rendering them? How are they rendered? Can you update your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for what you are working with and trying to do. For guidance, see [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) and then by extension, the [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using passing props from `screen1` to `screen2`

Try this code it's working !

// Screen1

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Screen2 from './Screen2';

function Screen1() {
  var [arr, setArr] = useState([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Screen2 data={arr} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Screen1;
```

//Screen2

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Screen2(props) {
  return (
    <div>{props.data}</div>
  );
}

export default Screen2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send **arr** to the Screen2 Component

For example:

Screen1.tsx

```
function Screen1() {

   var [arr, setArr] = useState([]);

   data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
   setArr(data);
   retrun(<Screen2 data = {arr}>)
}
```

Screen2.tsx

```
const Screen2 = (props) => {
  
    console.log(props.data);//[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    retrun(<div></div>);
 
}
```